# Issue With refresh / clear the select list for on change event in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two select boxes in my application, based on first select box selected value, the second select box values will display from DB. Now the issue is If I select one value in first select box the respective values will shown in second select box, again I change the value in first select box, the second selected box is does not clear the old values, I mean the new values are adding to the old list, It adding not updating. How can I clear the old values of my second select list for on change of my first select menu ?

My code is as follows,

Jquery:

```
 $("#select-choice").on('change', function(event) {
  //$('#select-choice-location option[value!="Select Location"]').remove();
          var catg = this.value;
          var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
          db.transaction(function (tx) {
          tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '"+catg+"';", [], function (tx, res) {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
          var opt  = '<option value="';
          opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
          opt += '">';
          opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
          opt += '</option>';
          $("#select-choice-location").append(opt);
           }
          $("#select-choice-location").listview('refresh');
         });
         });
     });
```

HTML code:

```
 <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice">
                      <option value="Select Category">Select Category</select>
              </select>
              <select name="select-choice-location" id="select-choice-location">
                  <option value="Select Location">Select Location</select>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to clear the old option htmls.

Use `empty()` it will clear the old one

Try this

```
$("#select-choice-location").empty().append(opt)
```

OR

```
$("#select-choice").on('change', function(event) {
              $("#select-choice-location").empty(); // Here you clear
              var catg = this.value;
              var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
              db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '"+catg+"';", [], function (tx, res) {
              var opt  = '<option value="">Select</option>';
              for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
              opt += '<option value="';
              opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
              opt += '">';
              opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
              opt += '</option>';

              $("#select-choice-location").append(opt);
               }
              $("#select-choice-location").listview('refresh');
             });
             });
         });
```

OR

```
$("#select-choice").on('change', function (event) {
    var catg = this.value;
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
        name: "MYDB"
    });
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '" + catg + "';", [], function (tx, res) {
            var opt  = '<option value="">Select</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                opt += '<option value="';
                opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                opt += '">';
                opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                opt += '</option>';
            }
            $("#select-choice-location").empty().append(opt);
            $("#select-choice-location").listview('refresh');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use .empty() in for loop, If there are multiple values, then i am able to get only last value.

Comment: If I use .empty() before for loop, it is satisfying the requirement, but I am not able to select the one option in second select menu

Comment: @user3300593 i posted two alters check with those and update me

Comment: Yeah I will check and let you know

Comment: Values are not repeating. But I am not able to select the first value of second select menu

Comment: @user3300593 add this default that makes always change in menu `var opt  = '<option value="">Select</option>';`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code

```
$("#select-choice").on('change', function(event) {
      //$('#select-choice-location option[value!="Select Location"]').remove();
              var catg = this.value;
              var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
              db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '"+catg+"';", [], function (tx, res) {
              for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
              var opt  = '<option value="';
              opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
              opt += '">';
              opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
              opt += '</option>';
    $("#select-choice-location").empty();
              $("#select-choice-location").append(opt);
               }
              $("#select-choice-location").listview('refresh');
             });
             });
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this it will work.

```
$("#select-choice").on('change', function (event) {
    $("#select-choice-location").empty(); // clear
    var catg = this.value;
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
        name: "MYDB"
    });
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '" + catg + "';", [], function (tx, res) {
            var opt = '<option value="">Select</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                opt += '<option value="';
                opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                opt += '">';
                opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                opt += '</option>';

                $("#select-choice-location").append(opt);
            }
            $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        });
    });
});
```

Refer here [JQM docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc3/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)

OR try this one and apply your custom functions.

```
var options = {
    Select1: ["A", "B", "C"],
    Select2: ["D", "E", "F"],
    Select3: ["G", "G", "I"]
};

$(function () {
    $('#firstSelect').change(function () {
        var x = $('#firstSelect :selected').val();
        $('#secondSelect').html("");
        for (index in options[x]) {
            $('#secondSelect').append('<option value="' + options[x][index] + '">' + options[x][index] + '</option>')
        };
    });
});
```

Refer this **<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/LZhQ8/17/)</kbd>**